# Looking for feedback for typeface

Tags: typography

I have created the following font:

[image: Perspective interference font]

I want to get feedback on

- aesthetic
- consistency

Is the font consistent and aesthetic?

I am not looking for feedback on

- kerning
- levelling

Please consider: the main purpose of the font is the demonstration of perspective interference.

Comment: Welcome on Graphics Design. When using this site, I recommend a less colloquial style. Also, please take care of the formatting of your question. I'll make a proposal edit, so that you know what question style is encouranged.

Comment: Hi B Mint Barna, thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a complete set of letter shapes is a hefty job. Making from them a usable computer font with decent typographic control doubles the effort. Congratulations!

Your work differs so much from the common habits that the text isn't easy to read. I bet it cannot be used in places where new complex texts are hoped to be recognized in one glance. Your second line is very difficult to parse reliably in a hurry. If it were Helvetica, one would see in a tenth of the second it's flipped.

It can be used in places where the purpose is to have an easily re-recognizable pattern such as a business logo, which is recognized as an image, not by reading it.

About the details: letter M (and m,too) seems to be dense, it pops out. Unfortunately, it pops out as easiest to recognize. The rest look out too sparse.

This can be solved in four ways:

1. leave it be
2. change the M
3. keep the M, change the rest
4. change all.

My opinion is to do #3.

Making A and R a little more different = recommended except if the purpose is to force someone to practise to see small differences.

Considering it perspective images of 3D shapes do not help reading, it's something extra which isn't the purpose of the written text. There's no shading - many of us will not see it's intended to be in perspective.

But if it had shading, it would be a bunch of separate levitating bended sheets, it would exaggerate the sparseness and bring it even further from something easily readable. See it:

[image]

Of course it's possible that I have guessed wrong bending directions. Illustrator's 3D extrusion effect can be useful if you search consistent one direction only extrusions. See an elementary example:

[image]

Comment: Great 3D alternative thanks, I was playing as well with the idea, what you are suggesting. You have right if I keep it flat its not so readable. The main goal was to leave it on the perceiver, give freedom of the perception, like a Rorschach test, an open question outcome.

Comment: Yeah, modelling this in 3d sounds like a great choice, especially since it's something designers of older fonts in this style likely wouldn't have been able to do. It's a really striking font! I just think maybe it needs a bit more work on the 'R' especially, which is a little hard to make out.

Answer (score 0):

here is the updated version.
The question is:

1. is it more readable?
2. and is it still consistent?

[image: h]